# First empty cell google script

Tags: google-sheets

I'm making a pointboard for Rummicum and the first row contains heading with players names in cells A1:D1. The pointboard is for 4 players and the first point goes to cell A2 and according to the rules the loosers get minus points and the winner get the positive sum of the loosers.
I use row E to sum up the minus points and then I want a script that checks witch of the 4 cells A2:D2 is empty and set the value in cell E2 into that empty cell.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question and your current issue. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your current script and the sample input and output situations you expect as the image? And, can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.